# Failed access to webservice ssl through php (curl) - ClientSoap

Tags: php, ssl, curl, wsdl, soap-client

When i use this Php code to access to the wsdl file not secured with authentication basic, it works very well.

```
<?php
try{

    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', false);
    $url = 'https://webservicexx:10443/Service.asmx?WSDL';
    $wsdl = get_wsdl($url); 
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl); 
    print_r($client);

} catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo $e;

} 

function get_wsdl($url) { 
    clearstatcache();
    $cache_file = "/var/www/webservice2/soap.wsdl." . md5($url); 
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $options = array(                           
                        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true,
                        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT=>true,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
                        CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents($cache_file, $data);
    return $cache_file; 

} 
?>
```

And when i try to access to the wsdl file secured with authentication basic (.NET), by changing the $option array, to add login and pass:

```
$options = array( 
  CURLOPT_POST=>true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH=>CURLAUTH_BASIC,
  CURLOPT_USERPWD=>'myLOGIN:myPASSWORD',
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true,
  CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT=>true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

I have problems on the file result. I don't get the wsdl file wich is secured, i have the page error on the file, on my server. That means that i don't have access to the file, because the authentication basic barrier, and the login and pass that i added on the $option array doesn't work.

How can i do it ?

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? Does it give you any error? Does `curl_exec()` return false? Check `curl_error()`

Comment: I wanted to mean curl works, but i have problems on the file result.
I don't get the wsdl file wich is secured, i have the page error as result on the file, on my server.
That means that i don't have access to the file, because the authentication basic barrier, and the login and pass that i added on the $option array doesn't work. How can i add Login and Pass ?

Answer (score 0):

Try also setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to `FALSE`

Comment: I added `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> false,` on the $option array. But on the file result("/var/www/webservice2/soap.wsdl.94399efcfdbc803b816c0bd116972989"), i have this HTML content:
`<h1>Bad Request (Invalid Number)</h1>` , and not the content of Wsdl file wich is secured